# Ошибка "The local variable may not have been initialized"

Tags: java

Я совсем недавно начал учить java, все это может выглядеть как костыль, но я искренне не понимаю, почему выдает ошибку, помогите пожалуйста

> Текст ошибки "The local variable a may not have been initialized"

```
// фрагмент кода, в котором объявляется переменные a,b 
      if (converter == 2) {
        int a,b; // объявление переменных 
        String[] romanArray = new String[]{"0", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"};
        
        for (int i = 0; i < romanArray.length; i++) {
            if (data[0].equals(romanArray[i])) {
                a = i;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < romanArray.length; i++) {
            if (data[1].equals(romanArray[i])) {
                b = i;
            }
        }
        
        // здесь я вызываю калькулятор, и тут же ошибка, что a, b не объявлены 
        int arabian = calc(a, b, (regexMathSymbol[mathSymbolIndex]));

// хотя в похожем случае все прекрасно работает 
    if(converter != 1){
        int a,b; // объявление переменных 


        a = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        b = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);

        if (a > 10 || b > 10) {
            System.out.println("Выражение не корректно!\nОдно или оба значений больше 10");
            return;
        }

        int arabian = calc(a, b, (regexMathSymbol[mathSymbolIndex]));
```

Comment: 1. Скопируй в вопрос текст ошибки, а не свою интерпретацию. 2. В каком именно месте объявлены a и b? 3. "Похожий" случай именно что похожий. В том смысле, что написан на том же языке программирований. На этом похожесть заканчивается.

Comment: Ошибка не в том, что переменная не объявлена, а в том, что она может быть не инициализирована (might not have been initialized). В первом случае переменным `a` и `b` значения присваиваются в условиях, которые теоретически могут быть не выполнены, тогда эти переменные не получат значения и с ними нельзя будет дальше работать. Во втором случае вы присваиваете им значения посредством `Integer::parseInt()`, поэтому значение либо точно будет присвоено, либо будет выброшено исключение данного метода. Поэтому дальнейшая работа с этими переменными возможна.

Comment: @Byb 
Это со всеми условными операторами будет такая ошибка? Или есть смысл пробовать?

Comment: Если инициализировать переменную только в блоке `if` - то конечно со всеми. Есть разные варианты, как этого избежать. 1) Сразу же ставить переменным значения по умолчанию (если в задаче значения по умолчанию имеют логику). 2) Инициализировать переменные не только в блоке `if`, но и во всех последующих блоках `if-else` и `else`. 3) Не использовать условие. Если значения по умолчанию не имеют логики, а значение не присвоилось (не выполнилось условие), то можно бросать исключение.

Comment: есть смысл пробовать что? представь, что условие ``if (data[0].equals(romanArray[i]))`` никогда не выполняется. Чему тогда будет равно a? Именно об этом тебе сообщается в ошибке.

Comment: @Эникейщик Понял, спасибо большое, задал им значение по 0 и все решилось